# Use property from output binding in parent component

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-output

I'm sure I must be missing something simple here, but I have a child component which emits an object via an Output event.  The parent component then subscribes to this output in a template like this:

```
<div class="tree-panel-container">
    <div class="tree-panel-content">
        <content-tree (contextSelected)="contextPanelSelected($event);"></content-tree>
    </div>
    <context-panel>
        <div class="context-panel">
            <h2>{{contextTitle}}</h2>
        </div>
    </context-panel>
</div>
```

Within the exported class of this same component is a function like this:

```
contextPanelSelected($event) {
    console.log($event);
}
```

The `console.log` in this function is correct, so I know the output object is coming through as expected.  What I want to do though is use a property on this output object to populate the value of `{{contextTitle}}` in the template.

Can anyone suggest how to do this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the following:

```
contextPanelSelected(value) {
  console.log(value);
  this.contextTitle = value;
}
```

In the following code:

```
(contextSelected)="contextPanelSelected($event)"
```

`$event` corresponds to the data that is sent through the event `contextSelected.emit('some text')`. This value can be passed as parameter of the `contextPanelSelected` method. This method is then responsible of setting this parameter into the `contextTitle` property of the component.

Comment: Thanks Thierry, I'd tried this but was getting a red squiggly underline in Visual Studio code saying `Property 'contextTitle' does not exist on type 'ContentComponent'` but I notice if I declare `contextTitle` as an empty variable outside of the `contextPanelSelected` function then it works fine. Perhaps this was just a tooling red-herring.

Comment: You're welcome! It's because TypeScript expects that you define the property before using it. Something like this: `contextTitle:string;`.